# Kivy Setting of button

Tags: python, kivy

I have two problems with button:a) placement icon on button and b) button's color.

a) For placement icon on button I use next script.This script cann't change position icon with resizing window. How must I repair script?

```
    self.layout = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, None), height=50)
    but = Button(on_press = self.DrawAbscissa)
    img = Image( source='abscissa.png',pos=(25,25))
    but.add_widget( img )
    self.layout.add_widget(but)
```

b) I want own color for button, but realy color doesn't corespond to rgb. I found solvining on stack overflow, but I don't understand to them. My script fot that:

```
but.background_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Can You help to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Color for button

The default texture is grey, so just setting the background color will give a darker result. To set a plain color, set the background_normal to ''.

```
but.background_normal = ''
but.background_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Thank You! Your advices were very usefull.